# Atualizar UpdatePanel após executar ajax sem refresh da página

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net

Boa tarde, preciso atualizar componentes que estão dentro de um `UpdatePanel` pagina `aspx` após inserção via `Ajax`. O `Ajax` executa uma função no `code-behind` em `C#`, e acontece o recarregamento da pagina inteira.

Ajax que executa o insert:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function FunctionComment(post_id, texto) {
        if (event.keyCode == 13) {
            var adv_id = $('#<%= hdfAdvogadoID.ClientID %>').val();

            try {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'Default.aspx/Comentar',
                    data: "{'ComentarioTexto':'" + texto
                    + "','AdvogadoID':'" + adv_id + "','PostID':'" + post_id + "'}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: false,
                    success: ShowMessage(" Comentadado!", 'Success', "icon fa fa-check"),
                    error: function (msg) {
                        alert(msg.d);
                    }
                });
            } catch (err) { }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Método responsável por inserir os dados no banco:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static string Comentar(string ComentarioTexto, int AdvogadoID, int PostID)
    {

        if (HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            ComentarioCRUD.SalvaComentario(ComentarioTexto, AdvogadoID, PostID);
            NotificationCRUD.AlterarFullNotificationComent();
        }

        return string.Empty;
    }
```

O código funciona perfeitamente mas após executar a pagina é atualizada inteira não apenas o UpdatePanel.

```
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="Repeater1" 
            OnItemDataBound="RptTime_ItemDataBound">
            <ItemTemplate>
            <codigos>....</codigos>
            <codigos>....</codigos>
                <asp:Repeater ID="RptComentario" 
                    OnItemDataBound="RptComentario_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
                    <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm"
                        placeholder="Pressione enter para postar comentário"
                        ID="txtPost" runat="server" AutoPostBack="false" autocomplete="off"
                        onkeypress='<%# String.Format("FunctionComment(\"{0}\", this.value);", Eval("PostID")) %>'>
                    </asp:TextBox>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Teria que usar um gatilho para atualizar apenas o `UpdatePanel` após o comando `success:` do `Ajax`!?

Design:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Você tem um  `<asp:ScriptManager>` no seu form?

Comment: @LeandroAngelo, sim ele herda da master page, sem `<asp:ScriptManager>` daria erro de compilação

Comment: Porque você não faz tudo pelo `UpdatePanel`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic tudo pelo `UpdatePanel` como assim? você poderia exemplificar para mim!?

Comment: O UpdatePanel, já tem tudo que precisa para atualizar a tela, somente o trecho de código, não precisaria nesse caso fazer um ajax e depois mandar ele atualizar ...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic eu vou tentar utilizando o evento `txtPost.TextChanged+=new EventHandler(txtPost_TextChanged);` pois ele está dentro de um `Repeater`

Comment: Estou montando um exemplo @Evandro, vai tentando ai.!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conforme as dicas do @Virgilio solucionei a questão de uma forma não muito elegante mas funcional:

Adicionei o evento `OnTextChanged` no `TextBox` dentro do `Repeater`:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
<ContentTemplate>
    <asp:Repeater runat="server" ID="RptTime" 
        OnItemDataBound="RptTime_ItemDataBound">
        <ItemTemplate>
        <codigos>....</codigos>
        <codigos>....</codigos>
            <asp:Repeater ID="RptComentario" 
                OnItemDataBound="RptComentario_ItemDataBound" runat="server">
                   <asp:TextBox CssClass="form-control input-sm"
         placeholder="Pressione enter para postar comentário" 
             OnTextChanged="txtPost_TextChanged"
                     onkeydown='<%# String.Format("setPostID(\"{0}\", this.value);", 
         Eval("PostID")) %>' ID="txtPost" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" 
         autocomplete="off"></asp:TextBox>
                <ItemTemplate>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:Repeater>
</ContentTemplate>
```

No Code-Behind C# atribui o evento no `ItemDataBound` do `Repeater`:

```
    protected void RptTime_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
    {            
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item)
        {
            TextBox txtPost = (TextBox)e.Item.FindControl("txtPost");
            txtPost.TextChanged += new EventHandler(txtPost_TextChanged);
    }
}
```

Logo criei o evento que executa o salve no banco, e demais ações:

```
protected void txtPost_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ComentarioCRUD.SalvaComentario(Convert.ToString(hdfTexto.Value), 
                Convert.ToInt32(hdfAdvogadoID.Value), 
                Convert.ToInt32(hdfPostID.Value));

        NotificationCRUD.AlterarFullNotificationComent();

        CarregaTimeline();
    }
```

E para obter o valor do `TextBox` usei `javascript`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function setPostID(post_id, txt) {
        document.getElementById("<%=hdfPostID.ClientID %>").value = post_id;
        document.getElementById("<%=hdfTexto.ClientID%>").value = txt;
    }
</script>
```

Executando dessa forma não há refresh na página apenas no UpdatePanel!

Answer (score 1):

Você está utilizando o componente [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx) que faz já o papel do `ajax` que está tentando fazer na sua pergunta, um exemplo básico vai ser demonstrado com um exemplo minimo:

Como vai funcionar:

Ao clicar no botão será enviado uma mensagem para ser adicionado em uma lista estática só para mostrar que não é atualizado toda a página somente o trecho do [UpdatePanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx):

> ASPX

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebFormUpdatePanel.aspx.cs" 
         Inherits="WebApplicationForms.WebFormUpdatePanel" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <h1>Sem Refresh</h1>
        <div>
            <label><%=DateTime.Now%></label>
        </div>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
        <div>
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
                <ContentTemplate>
                    <div>
                        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="TxtMensagem"></asp:TextBox>
                        <asp:Button ID="ButInserir" runat="server" Text="Inserir"
                                    OnClick="ButInserir_Click" />
                    </div>
                    <asp:Repeater ID="RptMensagem" runat="server">
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <div>
                                <asp:Label ID="LblMensagem" runat="server" 
                                           Text='<%#Container.DataItem%>'></asp:Label>
                            </div>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

> Code

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
namespace WebApplicationForms
{
    public partial class WebFormUpdatePanel : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public static List<string> Messages = new List<string>();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                Messages.Clear();
                RptMensagem.DataSource = Messages;
                RptMensagem.DataBind();
            }
        }

        protected void ButInserir_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Messages.Add(TxtMensagem.Text);
            TxtMensagem.Text = string.Empty;
            RptMensagem.DataSource = Messages;
            RptMensagem.DataBind();
        }
    }
}
```

---

No seu código em vez de fazer por esse método estático, pode colocar o código no evento padrão, por exemplo o do `Button` é `OnClick` e assim por diante.

Comment: O problema que estou enfrentando é que o `TextBox` tem que fica dentro do `Repeater` pois é montado várias postagens na página cada uma com um `Textbox` para ser comentado. E tenho que passar três parâmetros o `texto`, `IDdoUsuário` e o `IDdaPostagem` para salvar o comentário. Ele estando dentro do `Repeater` eu não consigo pegar via C#, preciso usar javascript no cliente para setar esses parâmetros.

Comment: @Evandro consegue sim.

Comment: Blz, vou referenciar os objetos no evento `Repeater.ItemDataBound` e tentar trabalhar com eles.

Comment: @Evandro me explica o problema é o que precisa fazer.

Comment: Vou fazer uma nova tentativa, e depois eu explico detalhadamente Virgilio